# Delete a Listview Item

Tags: vb.net, listview

I've created a Student Record, I have a Button **Delete** ,I want to display a **MessageBox** with warning When Delete Button is clicked and no **Item** is selected in my **Listview** Control.**You need to choose a Student**.

Here is my code

```
    If LvSV.SelectedItems.Count < 0 Then
       MessageBox.Show("You need to choose Student!")
    Else
        Dim items As ListViewItem
        items = LvSV.SelectedItems(0)
        items.Remove()
    End If
```

Comment: Please post only in English on this site, which includes the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear you have a small mistake in your code :-)

you should check for Count equal to 0 instead of < 0.

```
If LvSV.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
   MessageBox.Show("You need to choose Student!")
Else
    Dim items As ListViewItem
    items = LvSV.SelectedItems(0)
    items.Remove()
End If
```

Also your code assumes exactly 1 selected item. Maybe you want to generalize it to all selected items.

```
For each item As ListViewItem in LvSV.SelectedItems
   LvSV.Items.Remove(item)
Next
```

Cheers

Comment: @ĐứcThắng You should mark this as the answer and close the question.

Comment: @ĐứcThắng To accept the answer click the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. Not only will this help future readers but it will earn you a few reputation points.